# Docker Postgres Clear all Data

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm running postgress inside a docker container. I'm trying to completely remove it and re-install.

Everytime I start it seems to be 'restarting' rather than making a fresh instance.

When I re-start the new instance I get a message like this telling me when I last shut down the previous database:

```
postgres            | LOG:  database system was shut down at 2017-04-25 18:28:02 UTC
```

These are the steps I took in an attempt to completely remove the database.

```
  docker kill $(docker ps -q) # stop all containers
  docker rm $(docker ps -a -q) # remove all containers 
  docker rmi $(docker images -q) # remove all images
  docker network prune # remove all networks
  docker volume prune # remove all volumes
```

Yet I always get the log indicating when the previous database was shutdown. How can I completely remove all traces of the database?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can try:

```
docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -q)
```

Otherwise, the proper way to do it would be to do:

```
docker rm -f -v postgres_container_name
```

However, I don't think the volumes are the issue. When you do a `docker run --rm -it postgres` the entrypoint loads some configuration and restarts the database, so it is expected to see that message.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is I'm running a compose project (https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet-in-docker-examples/blob/master/compose/docker-compose.yml) which initially worked. I'm now running the exact same code but the database fails. So I'm trying to completely reset everything, with no luck. Are you saying that  I would see that message even if it was my first time running the database?

Comment: Yes, even if it was the first time, you will see that message.

Comment: Try to spin-up an empty docker-machine and see if you can reproduce. The issue is probably somewhere else though.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll try that. Docker machine refers to the host right?

Comment: Can be the host if you want/can, otherwise, you can use the tool docker-machine to spin up an isolated docker vm. https://docs.docker.com/machine/

Comment: I figured out my specific issue and posted an answer for future readers. Though I will leave this one as correct because it is likely more useful for most people. Cheers & thx!

Comment: This did not solved the problem for me. PostgreSQL still retrieves the same database after removing.

Answer (score 61):

For `docker-compose` the correct way to remove volumes would be `docker-compose down --volumes` or `docker-compose down --rmi all --volumes`.

For more information see https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/.

Answer (score 12):

It ended up being that docker compose was mounting folders on startup, these folders are specified in `docker-compose.yml` like so:

```
volumes:
  - ./code:/etc/puppetlabs/code/
  - ./puppet/ssl:/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/
  - ./puppet/serverdata:/opt/puppetlabs/server/data/puppetserver/
```

The folders are updated on use. By removing them I was able to fix my problem.

Comment: To complete the answer, the right way to remove the volume is by using:  
    docker volume prune

Answer (score 0):

Docker stop and `docker rm` will not work until you remove bind mount volume from your `docker-compose`.

Remove this from your docker-compose

```
 - ./data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

or delete everything from the host directory inside

./data/postgres